# Mapping network beyond my local network

Tags: networking, internet, home-networking, ping

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm curious about what goes on beyond my local network. Is there any way I can produce a visual map beyond my local network?

Comment: fyi, you can see what hops your connection goes through.  Open a command prompt and type tracert google.com and hit enter

Comment: +1 That's pretty cool. Is there any way I can identify what kind of devices are being listed. would they all be servers or is it showing me routers/switches as well?

Comment: they are all routers.  this site has a simple explanation of how it all works.  http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/internet-infrastructure1.htm

Comment: Great article. So presumably, the tracert ignores the initial query to the dns and just shows the path through various routers to it's final destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for traceroute, which traces the route from your computer to another network address.

The original is a Linux command for the command line, but there are plenty of visual versions for many operating systems (including online versions)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll do that. I had been using terms like network mapping to search on and was just getting local network mapping. I have ubuntu on a virtualbox, so a linux solution would be fine. Is there any particular program you would recommend?

Comment: You don't have to use Linux, there's plenty of Windows versions.  I usually just use the command line version (tracert in Windows does the same thing).